# What's the interpretation of the coefficient of a categorical variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

I am learning about MLR and I was wondering: if I have a linear regression with only two predictors and one of them is a categorical value (let's say: tall vs short), how do I interpret the β of that variable?

In this case:

$$ Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2. $$

Let's say X<sub>2</sub> is the categorical value and in my summary in R, it appears that variable (tall). How can interpret the β<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Welcome to this site. MLR = mutliple linear regression? Did you check our threads on the interpretation of regression coefficients, and how they are usually coded, especially in R (treatment coding)?

Comment: For more threads about this [see these links](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+coefficient+interpret+categor*+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on how you code your categorical variable. Let's assume that short is coded as $0$ and tall is coded as $1$ ($0$ and $1$ are the standard ways to code the categorical variables, though you could switch which number corresponds to which category without changing much).

It means that the tall subject is expected to be $\hat{\beta}_2$ more (in the response variable) than the short subject, with the other variable(s) the same for the tall and short subject.

You can think of the $\hat{\beta}_1$ as the (partial) derivative of the response with respect to its variable. With the categorical variable, differentiation doesn't quite make sense, but the difference does!